# Como hacer un graduador con valores

Tags: css

Quiero hacer algo como la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hay alguna libreria?

lo quiero usar para elegir un valor y luego mandar ese valor a backend.

Answer (score 4):

```
<input type="range">
```

Puedes definir max y mínimo e incluso los saltos.

```html
<input type="range" min="-10" max="10">
<input type="range" min="5" max="10" step="0.01">


<input type="range" list="tickmarks">

<datalist id="tickmarks">
   <option value="0" label="0%">
  <option value="10">   
  <option value="20">
  <option value="30">
  <option value="40">
  <option value="50" label="50%">
  <option value="60"> 
  <option value="70">
  <option value="80">
  <option value="90">
  <option value="100" label="100%">
 </datalist>
```

**Nota:** Actualmente, ningún navegador soporta todas estas características. Firefox no soporta ni marcas ni etiquetas, mientras que Chrome soporta las marcas pero no las etiquetas.

Te dejo la documentación!

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input/range

Comment: como puedo poner los valores? para que el usuario pueda elegir

Comment: Te puse una cosa pero veo que ya no va, la dejo para que quede constancia pero hay que buscar un método mejor.

Answer (score 0):

El valor que obtengo lo coloco en un div para saber que valor es el seleccionado

```html
<form name="registrationForm">
  <input type="range" name="ageInputName" id="ageInputId" value="24" min="-0.000001" max="1" step="0.0001" oninput="ageOutputId.value = ageInputId.value">
  <output name="ageOutputName" id="ageOutputId">10</output>
</form>
```

Comment: Esto es una respuesta?